# Compilar vários arquivos java na mesma pasta

Tags: java, compilação, cmd

Eu fiz um programa Java bem simples, usando o bloco de notas e compilando pelo **CMD**. 
O problema é que, mesmo os arquivos estando na mesma pasta, a classe que possui o método `main()` não compila.

Segue abaixo o código:

Classe Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nada nada = new Nada();

        nada.showVars();
        nada.setName("maisnada");
        nada.setN(16);
        System.out.println();
        nada.showVars();
    }
}
```

Classe Nada

```
public class Nada {
    private String nome;
    private int numeroQualquer;

    public Nada() {
        this.nome = "nada";
        this.numeroQualquer = 3;
    }

    public void setName(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.numeroQualquer = n;
    }

    public void showVars() {
        System.out.println(nome);
        System.out.println(numeroQualquer);
    }
}
```

Quando eu tento compilar o Main.java, dá o seguinte erro no **CMD**:

```
Main.java:3 error: cannot find symbol
               Nada nada = new Nada();
               ^
   symbol:   class Nada
   location: class Main
Main.java:3 error: cannot find symbol
               Nada nada = new Nada();
                               ^
   symbol:   class Nada
   location: class Main
2 errors
```

Sendo que os dois arquivos, Main.java e Nada.java, estão na mesma pasta, e o Nada.java compilou normalmente.

EDIT:

Consegui resolver o problema, era a a variável de ambiente 
**CLASSPATH**, ela estava como `%JAVA_HOME%\lib` em vez de `.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib`.

O comando que eu usava para compilar era esse:

```
javac Main.java
```

Obrigado a todos que responderam.

Comment: Que comando você usou pra compilar? Você verificou se a pasta atual - `.` - está no `CLASSPATH`? Por exemplo: `javac -cp . Main.java`

Comment: Eu usei javac Main.java

Comment: [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/87632/edit) sua questão e adicione o comando que está usando para compilar.

Comment: Você está usando pacotes?

Comment: Não, mas já consegui resolver, era o CLASSPATH mesmo. Valeu a ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa compilar **todos** os arquivos *.java* e não apenas o **Main**.
*Como você não colocou qual comando está usando para compilar, suponho que seja este o seu erro*

Para fazer isso você pode rodar o comando:

> javac *.java

O * é um *wildcard* muito comum que quer dizer **tudo** ou **todos**. Nesse caso o **.java* quer dizer **todos os arquivos *.java* nesta pasta**.

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer o seguinte comando:

```
javac diretorio/*.java
```